# How to access action value inside saga function

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, redux-saga

I would to like to access a value from home.js inside my saga but I am getting Typerror undefined is not an object evaluating payload.val.

I want to carry val from SET_RSSI action type to PERSIST_RSSI_SUCCESS.

is it possible to access it in redux-saga ?

action.js:

```
export const $setRssi = val => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const URL = getState().connect.URL;
    dispatch({type: Types.SET_RSSI, val, URL});
  };
};
```

saga.js:

```
    function* persistRssi({payload}) {
          let {val, URL} = payload;
          try {
            yield axios
              .post('http://' + URL + ':8080/rest/items/rssi', val, config)
              .then(response => {
                console.log('STATUS RESPONSE FROM PERSIST RSSI' + response.status);
              });
            yield put({type: Types.SET_BATT_SUCCESS, val});
          } catch (error) {
            yield put({type: Types.SET_BATT_FAILURE});
          }
        }
    function* actionWatcher() {
      yield takeLatest(Types.SET_RSSI, persistRssi);
    }
export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([actionWatcher()]);
}
```

reducer.js:

```
import * as Types from '../../actions/Types';
import defaultState from './state';
module.exports = (state = defaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case Types.SCANNING:
      return {
        ...state,
        scanning: !action.val,
      };
    case Types.SET_RSSI_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        rssi: action.val,
      };
    case Types.SET_RSSI_FAILURE:
      return state;  
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I am not sure about the logic here, does't confirm with saga logic or not ???

Answer (score 1):

The object you get as parameter in saga is the action object itself. You are dispatching this action object.

```
{type: Types.SET_RSSI, val, URL}
```

There is no `payload` property there. So change this

```
function* persistRssi({payload}) {
```

To:

```
function* persistRssi(payload) {
```

Or even better rename `payload` to `action` since `payload` can confuse people who use the https://github.com/redux-utilities/flux-standard-action action object schema.